# How do Chern classes behave under connected sums?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I often see people talking about Chern classes of manifolds like $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# \mathbb{CP}^2$, or $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$, where $\#$ denotes connected sum and the bar denotes the opposite orientation.

I know what Chern classes are, and I know that if a complex vector bundle $E$ splits as $E_1 \oplus E_2$, then
$$c_k(E) = \sum_{i + j = k} c_i(E_1)\wedge c_j(E_2).$$
However, I've never seen a formula relating the Chern classes of (the tangent bundle of) a complex manifold $M \# N$ and those of $M$ and $N$. So my questions are:

**1)** Does such a formula exist, and where can I read about it?

**2)** How does one compute the Chern classes of connected sums of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$?

For the time being, I'm actually more interested in **2)**, but any information is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: If $M\# N$ is a complex manifold, then it is not necessarily the case that $M$ or $N$ is a complex manifold. Furthermore, the manifolds $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ do not admit almost complex structures, so they do not have Chern classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2, one can find the following in Daniel Huybrechts' complex geometry (p.98 - 102).

The connected sum $Y :=\mathbb {CP}^2 \# \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ is diffeomorphic to the blowup of $X:=\mathbb {CP}^2$ at one point. Call $E$ the expectional divisor and $\sigma : Y\to X$ the blowup map, then

$$K_Y = \sigma^* K_X \otimes [E] \Rightarrow c_1(Y) = \sigma^* c_1(X) - c_1([E])$$